# Opening .pdf files in browser from Amazon S3 with AWS Key and Signature attributes?

Tags: url, amazon-s3, cross-browser

When I try clicking a pdf link on my website in Chrome and FF it does not do anything. I can right-click and save as but I cannot open it up within the browser. Both browsers have adobe reader enabled and works when I remove the AWS Key and signature.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/sample.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=&Expires=&Signature= // Does not open

https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/mypdf.pdf // Opens fine
```

It works fine in both IE and Opera. Any way to bypass this?

Comment: You want to open it so Adobe Reader plugin would kick in and open the file inside the browser, or you want to download it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason of your problem is really obvious, but could be difficult to resolve. When you open nonKey link

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/mypdf.pdf
```

browser gets .pdf extension at the end of the link and tries to download it. But when you have additional request params your link is not ends with .pdf and that may cause the problem.

It looks like your uploaded pdf file got no metadata for content-type. If you don't have **Figure out content types automatically** checkbox checked during upload, try to set content-type manually by adding metadata

```
content-type: application/pdf
```

Other idea is to make browser think that the link is ending with .pdf, so try to download with this link:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/sample.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=a&Expires=b&Signature=c&file=sample.pdf
```

Comment: Then I am getting "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." error